# Uncover sentence intersections in a corpus with NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, text-mining

I have a corpus of documents and I'm trying to uncover instances in which complete and exact sentences appear across the corpus, possibly with NLTK or some other method in Python.

For example, suppose the corpus consists of ten text files and one or many of the files contain the sentence: *the cat sat on the mat*. How would I go about identifying matches of that sentence across the corpus?

Something I've tried is to split the files into one sentence per line using a very clunky regex and then used `set` to find the intersection between two texts. This works, but isn't scaleable to big corpus.

Is anyone aware of a scaleable and more robust approach to this task in Python?

Comment: Use NLTK sentence tokenizer (`nltk.set_tokenize()`) to extract sentences. Build a dictionary where sentences are keys and sets of files that contain them are values. At the end the entries that have more than one file name are duplicated.

Comment: @DYZ Thanks! That makes sense. I'm sorry to be cheeky, but are you able to give me a steer on how I build that dictionary?